# Unexpected '{', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$'

Tags: php, laravel, syntax-error

I have a laravel 4 web app using a third party package. It worked fine on my localhost but i've uploaded it to appfog and it's throwing the following error in the thirdparty plugin:

`syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$'`

Somewhere on this line:

`Mail::{$mailMethod}(Config::get('saasframe::email.view'), (array)$subscription, function($message) use ($user)`

You can view the full error details here:

[chris-till-staging-app.eu01.aws.af.cm](http://chris-till-staging-app.eu01.aws.af.cm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mail::{$mailMethod}
```

Perhaps this?

Are you calling a static variable? If so, try

```
Mail::$mailMethod
```